# system("command") string in string problem

Tags: c++, command, system

have a problem with `system("command")`.
I want to start *.exe* with some parameters but `"B0 P1"` cant be compiled because of use `""` in command string. Any solution/tips :)?

```
int main() {
    system ("start C:\\PROGRA~2\\BEL\\Realterm\\realterm.exe FIRST=1 SENDSTR= "B0 P3" ");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping them?  How come you are not escaping the backslashes?

Comment: You can escape the quotes inside your string with a backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape quote characters inside your string:

```
int main() {
    system ("start C:\\PROGRA~2\\BEL\\Realterm\\realterm.exe FIRST=1 SENDSTR= \"B0 P3\" ");
}
```

In c++ 11 you can also use string literal R"(...)" if you don't want to escape characters:

```
int main() {
    system ( R"(start C:\PROGRA~2\BEL\Realterm\realterm.exe FIRST=1 SENDSTR= "B0 P3")" );
}
```